# Android offline documentation is different from online documentation

Tags: android, offline

Just this week, I downloaded the latest Android SDK (20.0.3). After I downloaded the offline documentation (supposedly API 16), I saw that it contains older material than from what is online. When I explored the offline documentation, the ADT version it mentions is 20.0.0 when the latest is 20.0.3 already. Also, there are some parts of the doc which are different from the actual sample source code. For instance, when I was following the "Build a Simple User Interface Page", the offline doc states that the LinearLayout is used in the default Hello World app of Eclipse, when in fact, the Relative Layout is used (this is correctly stated in the online documentation).

Is there a way to get the latest version of the documentation for offline use or is that the what we really get in the bundle?

Comment: AFIK, android haven't released new doc version

Comment: you mean for offline (the one you download from sdk?)? but they regularly update the online one?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it is updated, you can get those with SDK manager,

Comment: but i did get the latest documentation, and still it is different from the online version (which is much updated).

Comment: do you get the green version or the new fancy grey version?

Comment: sorry what are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

> Just this week, I downloaded the latest Android SDK (20.0.3)

That is not an Android SDK version. That is an Android tools version.

> Is there a way to get the latest version of the documentation for offline use or is that the what we really get in the bundle?

The online version is always newer. Generally, the offline documentation only gets updated on formal Android SDK releases. Also, some things are only ever on the online version (e.g., device dashboards).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

[Android Documentation in CHM format](http://code.google.com/p/android-chm-documentation/downloads/detail?name=Android.4.2.documentation-1.6.zip&can=2&q=)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pdf version  for most sections that are built monthly with details of what has changed in the previous month. The website has been split into sections for each book.

[https://www.docand.com/](https://docand.com)

```
Design ………………….. https://docand.com/android-design-methods-book/
Training…………………. https://docand.com/training-in-android-book/
Android Components………… https://docand.com/a-guide-to-android-api-components-book/
Google Services…………… https://docand.com/android-google-available-services-book/ 
Distribution Methods……….. https://docand.com/android-distribution-methods-book/
Tools of the Android Developer…………… https://docand.com/tools-of-the-android-developer-book/
```

The sections are all available as a preview and as a download for free.